# Generic Method Calls

Tags: java, generics

I have been experimenting with Generic and soon enough I've run into something I cannot explain.
 **For example**:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //We cannot create List<?> l = new ArrayList<?>();
        List<?> l = MagicClass.factory();
    }
    static class MagicClass {
        public static <T> List<T> factory() {
            return new ArrayList<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how `<T>` can be explicit type parameter while this one

```
<?>
```

is undefined.

Comment: how <T> in factory() method can be explicit

Comment: Well, `T` could be the upper bound of `?` and since it doesn't have one, it could be interpreted as `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating a generic type using the wildcard generates a compilation error since the wildcard means *any type*, while the instantiated `ArrayList` should have a concrete type. The wildcard can be used for variables or parameter types, but not when creating an instance of the generic type.

This is mentioned as well in [this tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

> In generic code, the question mark (`?`), called the *wildcard*, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). **The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.**

On the other hand, in the `factory` method, `T` is a type parameter that will be inferred by the compiler, and since the `List<?>` denotes any type, it is accepted by the compiler.

Comment: When you say : "'T' is a type parameter that will be inferred by the compiler", what exactly kind of type you mean?

Comment: @Anarantt See [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). AFAIK, the actual type of `T` would be determined by the compiler depending on the invocation. FYI, I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878132/generic-method-type-inference-when-the-target-type-has-a-wildcard) to know more about it.

Answer (score 2):

`<?>` is a [*wildcard*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), it means as much as: *"any type you like"*. Now since `<?>` thus doesn't make any assumption of the type used, `T` can only be more *specialized*. Thus Java sees `Foo<T>` as `Foo<?>`. On the other hand **it is rather unwise to do so**, because Java has less means to type-check the code. As a result, Java will normally deny to invocate any method where the type parameter is used as input.

> **Example**: the following code won't compile:
>
> ```
>     ArrayList<?> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
>     foo.add("bar");
> ```
>
> This because, Java doesn't know what the `T` in `foo` is. It is possible that `foo` is a `ArrayList<Integer>`, thus to be safe, it is not allowed.

It can be used if you want for instance to make a method that can accept all kinds of `List<?>` instances, regardless of the objects stored in them.

**You can never construct an instance with a wildcard**

The following code won't compile:

```
ArrayList<?> foo = new ArrayList<?>();
```

This because at the time of construction, Java has to know which type you will choose.

---

But in many cases it is used as *bounded wildcards*. With as typical example:

```
public void drawAll(List<? extends Shape> shapes) {
    //...
}
```

This method is given a list of `Shape`'s. Now if you write this as `List<Shape>`, it requires you to provide an `ArrayList<Shape>` or `LinkedList<Shape>` or another collection. But perhaps you have *specialized* your collection to contain only `Quadrilateral` instances (`Rectangle`, `Square`, `Trapezium`). If you would use `ArrayList<Quadrilateral>` on a function `drawAll(List<Shape> shapes)`, you would get a Type-error: indeed, a `List<Quadrilateral>` is not a `List<Shape>`, but using bounderies, you enforce that the generic type `extends` for instance from another type.

Answer (score 0):

> We cannot create List l = new ArrayList();

If you really wanted to do it, you could do

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

or

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<Math>();
```

or

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<SomeBogusIrrelevantClass>();
```

There are all correct. Just pick any type that satisfies the bounds; it doesn't even have to be related to what you're doing.

From this, you can see why what you're trying to do is absurd -- you have a list that could be `ArrayList<Math>` or could be `ArrayList<SomeBogusIrrelevantClass>` (you don't know). So what can you do with it? Not much.

You can't add anything (besides `null`) to it. So you have a list where the elements can only have value `null`; the only thing that can vary is how many `null`s. But in that case, you might as well use an integer.