# Generic method type inference when the target type has a wildcard

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I understand that the compiler uses the target type to determine the type argument that makes the generic method invocation applicable. For instance, in the following statement:

```
List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();
```

where the `Collections.emptyList` has a type parameter `T` in its signature

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
```

In this case, the inferred type argument for `T` is `String`.

Now consider the following:

```
List<?> listTwo = Collections.emptyList();
```

What is the inferred type in this case? Is it `Object`? Or it doesn't really matter due to the wildcard telling the compiler any type is possible?

Comment: `?` isn't "any type," it's "unknown type."  Other than that, what Oliver said.

Comment: As a tangent, it's not clear what you'd then do with a `List<?>`, as you can't put anything in it.

Comment: `?` means that you don't intend on using any method in `List` that requires the parameter or return type `T`.  If you do, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes indeed and I'm not using this in actual code but just wanted to know the inferred type for this case.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So if I understand correctly, the concept of an inferred type argument could extend to include wildcards if the compiler deems it acceptable?

Comment: @DannyDaglas No compilation error when that value is `null`.

Comment: Good point Gábor!  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each usage of a wildcard has a distinct type associated with it. (Usually the JLS refers to this as being a "fresh type".) This is how for example a compiler error like this works:

```
List<?> list0 = ... ;
List<?> list1 = ... ;
list0.add(list1.get(0)); // error
```

Because it's the case that `list0` and `list1` are given separate types by the compiler such that for the most part

```
reference_type_of(List<?>) != reference_type_of(List<?>)
```

You can begin to see how this fits in to type inference if you try something like

```
{
    List<?> list0 = ... ;
    List<?> list1 = ... ;
    test(list0, list1);
}
static <T> void test(List<T> list0, List<T> list1) {}
```

Where the compiler emits an error that actually tells us a little bit about the types that it has generated for `list0` and `list1`.

```
error: method test in class Ideone cannot be applied to given types;
    test(list0, list1);
    ^
  required: List<T>,List<T>
  found: List<CAP#1>,List<CAP#2>
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that
          argument type List<CAP#2> conforms to formal parameter type List<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>test(List<T>,List<T>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

(My emphasis in bold.) These `CAP#...` types were generated during [capture conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10). What it's showing us is that when the method invocation expression was examined, `list0` and `list1` were given distinct types from each other. (And for those that need an explanation for the error: it's because the declaration of `test` asserts that both Lists must have the same `T`.)

So since we now know that a wildcard gets associated a reference type, we can see that in a case like

```
List<?> empty = Collections.emptyList();
```

The invocation will be inferred as something like "a fresh type where the upper bound is Object". Or symbolically we could say the compiler might see something like

```
// target type       -->       inferred invocation type
//     v                           v
List<CAP#1> empty = Collections.<CAP#1>emptyList();
```

Although: of course we are always guessing a little bit because it's up to the compiler how it implements this. In theory, for a case like the above trivial assignment of `emptyList()`, it would not have to do work to generate the correct bytecode.

<sub>Also, I am sorry, I don't feel like spec scouring today. Essentially the type inference here works by generating a set of constraints to demonstrate that the method invocation should or should not compile. The algorithm described in [18.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2) incorporates a wildcard in this way.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> What is the inferred type in this case? Is it Object? Or it doesn't
>   really matter due to the wildcard telling the compiler any type is
>   possible?

On one level, it's kind of a philosophical question, because the type argument does not have any effect on the compiled bytecode, so it doesn't really matter what it is specifically. The only thing that matters is whether or not it's impossible to satisfy the bounds and context. As long as the compiler can prove that there *exists* some type that could work, then in my opinion, it should be able to go ahead and compile it without needing to come up with an actual type.