# could not be able to load data into javafx tabels

Tags: javafx

need help... [here is the output of table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtMww.png) 
i could not be able to find why it's not displaying any row's data except columns.I mean it displays only database columns 
Here is the code

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
     TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableview = new TableView();
     ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     Connection c = DBConnect.connect(); 
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY.CUSTOMER";
     ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
     ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
     int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
         System.out.println(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
         TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
         tableview.getColumns().add(col);

     }
     while(rs.next()) {
         ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

         for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
             row.add(rs.getString(i));
         }
         data.add(row);
         System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
     }
     tableview.setItems(data);
     rs.close();

     Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);        
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();
 }
```

Hope you people will find the wrong part. 
I am not getting any kind of error too.

Comment: You need cell value factories. See this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

Comment: i followed the steps given by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808905/javafx-dynamic-tableview-is-not-showing-data-from-the-database but still could not find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a [`cellValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty). Otherwise the `TableView` doesn't know which part of the item to display in a specific column:

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
final int index = i; // is this the index corresponding to the list element to display???
col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.stringValueAt(cellData.getValue(), index));
```