# How is the type inferred when using wildcards in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have read [Angelika langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20argument%20inference%20in%20general?) and it discusses type inference in case of a type argument without wildcard.

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();// type inference
```

I get that. But what happens in the following two cases?

```
ArrayList<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<? extends Number> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

What types are inferred by the compiler above and why?

I read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878132/generic-method-type-inference-when-the-target-type-has-a-wildcard) also, but it only discusses the case where the argument is `List<?>` and not the provided examples.

Comment: Why is this closed? The suggested question does not answer this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878132/generic-method-type-inference-when-the-target-type-has-a-wildcard is

Comment: @matt That is not entirely correct. You can't use wildcards for the objects themselves, only for variables, fields and parameters. The second and the third will both be inferred as `ArrayList<Number>`. That is, absent an explicit type parameter, it will use the upper bound of the `super` or the lower bound of the `extends`.

Comment: The usage of these is a bit weird. `? extends Number` says the List is something that extends Number. Which means you can get Numbers out, but you cannot put anything in. `? super Number` says you can put Numbers in (they're a subclass of the mysterious ?), but you can only get Object out.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't know what that means though. How are you going to use it? list1 has the generic parameter <? super Number> sure you can cast it to a List<Number> but the generic parameter doesn't change the type the list is, it affects what you do.

Comment: @matt The question is about type inferencing. What type is inferred by the compiler when it encounters <> in the given two cases. Your response is technically incorrect and also irrelevant.

Comment: "That is, absent an explicit type parameter, it will use the upper bound of the super or the lower bound of the extends" if that is the case, is it in the other answer? Is there a JLS reference. Also when you say "upper bound" wouldn't that be Object?

Comment: @matt It may not be usable, but the inferred type is `ArrayList<Number>`. You can see this if instead you create an anonymous class (e.g. `ArrayList<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>() {};` and then print `list1.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName()`, which will output `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Number>` (and same for `list2`).

Comment: @matt Object is the lower bound from my perspective, but maybe I switched up my terminology.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am [reading here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) because I might be mixed up and it starts by talking about both.

Comment: @matt OK, that means I switched/mixed up the terminology.

Comment: @matt This is covered by [chapter 18 Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-18.html) of the JLS, but I find that chapter hard to read, and I currently don't have the bandwidth to identify exactly which rules apply here.

Comment: I agree, the other answer is incomplete. You should probably answer with your comment and your proof. The language in chapter 18 is pretty heave as they're creating a whole mathematics for reducing the problem and not such a simple example as above.

Comment: All are `Number`.But don’t worry, because generics are used for compile-time checking.If you declare `? extends Number`, you are destined not to be able to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has an answer in the comments, based on these two claims:

- You can't use wildcards for the objects themselves, only for variables, fields and parameters.
- Absent an explicit type parameter, it will use the upper bound of the super or the lower bound of the extends.

I do not understand how these conclussions are drawn from the JLS. In the mean time here is an example.

Both cases create a List. One way to see this is to create an anonymous inner class.

```
ArrayList<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>() {};
System.out.println(list1.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
```

Which will output,

> list1 ==> []
> java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Number>

The lower bound case,

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>() {};
System.out.println(list1.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
```

Which outputs:

> list1 ==> []
> java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Number>